# Omniauth login without refreshing the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm using the Omniauth gem to let my users sign up through twitter.

I want the omniauth process to happen behind the scenes, so I'm trying to make the link to `/auth/twitter` a `remote: true` link. However, when I do that, I get "Callback phase initiated", and then nothing more.

I assume this is because the omniauth gem only recognizes standard calls. How do I get it to respond to AJAX calls?

```
= link_to "Sign in with Twitter", twitter_signin_path, remote: true
```

Comment: Check my answer over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149952/omniauth-authorization-call-with-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because oauth authorization flow involve redirection to the provider website.

This step is happening on twitter.com. Its not possible to complete the flow from javascript AJAX request.