# Omniauth authorization call with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, omniauth

I have omniauth working fine in my Rails 3 app when using it as a link:

```
link_to("Connect Twitter", "/auth/twitter", :id => "connect-to-twitter")
```

Now I want to call '/auth/twitter' through ajax. However, nothing is returned after the request phase. Here is the last log entry:

```
Started GET "/auth/twitter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-30 17:53:02 -0700
(twitter) Request phase initiated.
```

Here is my ajax code (in Coffeescript):

```
$("#connect-to-twitter").live("click", ->
  alert('get twitter')
  $.get('/auth/twitter', (data) ->
    alert(data)
  )
  return false
)
```

(I know this question has been asked before here, but I haven't seen any real answer to it.)

Comment: Hey, have you found any solution yet? I just had the same purpose though I'm still struggeling

Comment: Nope, never did figure this out.

Comment: Hmm, I just want to bypass using the fb/twitter JS api :/ Though it seems it's not possible without.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know the question is bit old but I'll still answer it . After facing the issue for and looking to achieve the same what the OP intended to  I did this

I wrote a middleware and inserted in right above the `Omniauth` here how the middleware look

```
class OmniAuthMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if request.xhr? and status == 302 and request.path_info =~ /\/auth\/\w+\z/ and body.class == Rack::BodyProxy
      location = headers["Location"]
      body = ActionDispatch::Response.new
      headers = {'Content-Type'=>'text/javascript; charset=utf-8'}
      body.body = ["window.location.href='#{location}'"]
      body.headers = headers
      status = 200
    end
    [status,headers,body]
  end
end
```

And here how I insert by middleware in the middleware stack

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before OmniAuth::Builder,OmniAuthMiddleware
```

Here how my middleware stack look

```
...
...
...
use Warden::Manager
use Rack::Mongoid::Middleware::IdentityMap
use ExceptionNotifier
use OmniAuthMiddleware
use OmniAuth::Builder
run PoasterApi::Application.routes
```

With this I was able to achieve what I wanted

**Note**: I haven't found any info about ajax stuff in the Omniauth doc and since I was running against time hence I implemented this fix (since a google search never gave me a favourable answer)  . It could be possible that Omniauth support ajax response as well but as said I was not able to find one in the documentation . The answer is for those users who wish  to implement the exact same functionality but just not sure how to achieve it in Omniauth .

I'm still looking at Omniauth to find if their exist a way to do this directly in Omniauth by setting/tweaking the configuration

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Two things: First, since you're using localhost, you'll have to set the port number (assuming 3000), so the endpoint should be **localhost:3000**. Secondly, you also have to set a redirect, which should also be **localhost:3000**.